# Algorithm - What is the critical parameter to derive relationships across resources in VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-sdk, snmp, vpc

Goal is to visualise the relationship of resources within AWS account(may have multiple VPC's).

This would help daiy operations. For example: Resources getting affected after modifying the security group

---

Each resource has [ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) assigned in AWS cloud

Below are some example relationsships among resources:

Route table `has-many` relationship with subnets

NACL `has-many` relationship with subnets

Availability zone `has-many` relationship with subnets

IAM resource `has-many` regions

`has-many` is something like compose relation

security group has `association` relation with any resource in VPC

NACL has `association` relation with subnet only

We also have [VPC flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) to find the relationships

---

Using AWS SDK's,

1)

For on-prem networks, we take IP range and send ICMP requests to verify existence of devices in the IP range and then we send snmp query to classify the device as (windows/linux/router/gateway etc...)

How to find the list of resources allocated within an AWS account? How to classify resources?

2)

What are the parameters that need to be queried from AWS resources(IAM, VPC, subnet, RTable, NACL, IGW  etc...) that help create relationsip view of the resources within an AWS account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to stitch your ressources together by your self in your app. you can use the ressourcegrouptagging api from aws. take a look on ressourcegroups in your aws console. there you can group things based on tags. then, you can tag the groups itself. requesting with the boto3 python lib will give you a bunch of information. read about boto3, its huge! another thing which might be intresting for you is "aws config".. there you can have your compliance, config histoty, relationship of ressources and plenty of other stuff!

also, check out aws cloudwatch for health monitoring

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/resource-config-reference.html